# Using MVC5, How can I databind a collection to a DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I am developing an MVC5 application. I have a controller/view to Create new AccountDtos. An AccountDto has a collection (List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>) of AssociatedVendors. My AccountDto is a simple POCO and looks like this

```
public class AccountDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AssociatedVendors { get; set; }
    . . . 
}
```

In my view, I have two multi-select controls (see image below). One lists all Vendors, the other lists the vendors I select. The goal is to allow me to select a sub-set of vendors to associate with my AccountDto upon creation.

[image]

I add items from either select control using javascript

```
    $("#vendor-add").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#vendor-source-select").find(':selected').appendTo($("#vendor-dest-select"));
    });
    
    $("#vendor-addall").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#vendor-source-select").children().appendTo($("#vendor-dest-select"));
    });
    
    $("#vendor-remove").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#vendor-dest-select").find(':selected').appendTo($("#vendor-source-select"));
    });
    
    $("#vendor-removeall").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#vendor-dest-select").children().appendTo($("#vendor-source-select"));
    });
```

The problem is databinding. I am trying to databind the select control on the right to the AssociatedVendors that I select. I have tried various flavours of ListBoxFor and DropdownListFor such as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AssociatedVendors, 
new SelectList(Model.AssociatedVendors.Select(s => new SelectListItem{Text = s.Value, Value = s.Key})), 
htmlAttributes: new { id = "vendor-dest-select", @class = "vendor-select", multiple = "multiple" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AssociatedVendors, new SelectList(Model.AssociatedVendors, "Key", "Value"))

@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.AssociatedVendors, new SelectList(Model.AssociatedVendors, "Key", "Value"))
```

When I submit my view back to the controller, the AssociatedVendors property is always 0 length. I'd appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a kind of fix. I realise that I cannot data bind to the same list that's being edited, so I added a new collection of AssocVendorIds to my AccountDto.  Then I can data bind to that collection using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.AssocVendorIds, 
new MultiSelectList(Model.Vendors.Select(s => new SelectListItem{Value = s.Id.ToString(), Text = s.Name}), 
"Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "vendor-dest-select", @class = "vendor-select", multiple = "multiple" })
```